# RedHat Linux phpMyAdmin Not installing

Tags: mysql, linux, phpmyadmin, server, redhat

I tried to install PHPMyAdmin in RedHat Linux server but it is not installing properly,

```
yum -y install phpmyadmin
```

But it is Getting Error with some packages you can see log here, how can i fix this?

```
    --> Running transaction check
    ---> Package phpMyAdmin.noarch 0:4.4.15.8-2.el7 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: php-mysqli >= 5.3.7 for package: phpMyAdmin-4.4.15.8-2.el7.noarch
    --> Processing Dependency: php-mbstring >= 5.3.7 for package: phpMyAdmin-4.4.15.8-2.el7.noarch
    --> Processing Dependency: php-gd >= 5.3.7 for package: phpMyAdmin-4.4.15.8-2.el7.noarch
    --> Processing Dependency: php-xmlwriter for package: phpMyAdmin-4.4.15.8-2.el7.noarch
    --> Processing Dependency: php-tcpdf-dejavu-sans-fonts for package: phpMyAdmin-4.4.15.8-2.el7.noarch
    --> Processing Dependency: php-tcpdf for package: phpMyAdmin-4.4.15.8-2.el7.noarch
    --> Processing Dependency: php-php-gettext for package: phpMyAdmin-4.4.15.8-2.el7.noarch
    --> Running transaction check
    ---> Package php-gd.x86_64 0:5.4.16-42.el7 will be installed
    ---> Package php-mysql.x86_64 0:5.4.16-42.el7 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.4.16-42.el7 for package: php-mysql-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64
    ---> Package php-php-gettext.noarch 0:1.0.11-12.el7 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: php-mbstring for package: php-php-gettext-1.0.11-12.el7.noarch
    ---> Package php-tcpdf.noarch 0:6.2.11-1.el7 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: php-tidy for package: php-tcpdf-6.2.11-1.el7.noarch
    --> Processing Dependency: php-posix for package: php-tcpdf-6.2.11-1.el7.noarch
    --> Processing Dependency: php-mbstring for package: php-tcpdf-6.2.11-1.el7.noarch
    --> Processing Dependency: php-bcmath for package: php-tcpdf-6.2.11-1.el7.noarch
    ---> Package php-tcpdf-dejavu-sans-fonts.noarch 0:6.2.11-1.el7 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: dejavu-sans-fonts for package: php-tcpdf-dejavu-sans-fonts-6.2.11-1.el7.noarch
    ---> Package php-xml.x86_64 0:5.4.16-42.el7 will be installed
    ---> Package phpMyAdmin.noarch 0:4.4.15.8-2.el7 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: php-mbstring >= 5.3.7 for package: phpMyAdmin-4.4.15.8-2.el7.noarch
    --> Running transaction check
    ---> Package dejavu-sans-fonts.noarch 0:2.33-6.el7 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: dejavu-fonts-common = 2.33-6.el7 for package: dejavu-sans-fonts-2.33-6.el7.noarch
    ---> Package php-pdo.x86_64 0:5.4.16-42.el7 will be installed
    ---> Package php-php-gettext.noarch 0:1.0.11-12.el7 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: php-mbstring for package: php-php-gettext-1.0.11-12.el7.noarch
    ---> Package php-process.x86_64 0:5.4.16-42.el7 will be installed
    ---> Package php-tcpdf.noarch 0:6.2.11-1.el7 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: php-mbstring for package: php-tcpdf-6.2.11-1.el7.noarch
    --> Processing Dependency: php-bcmath for package: php-tcpdf-6.2.11-1.el7.noarch
    ---> Package php-tidy.x86_64 0:5.4.16-7.el7 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: libtidy-0.99.so.0()(64bit) for package: php-tidy-5.4.16-7.el7.x86_64
    ---> Package phpMyAdmin.noarch 0:4.4.15.8-2.el7 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: php-mbstring >= 5.3.7 for package: phpMyAdmin-4.4.15.8-2.el7.noarch
    --> Running transaction check
    ---> Package dejavu-fonts-common.noarch 0:2.33-6.el7 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: fontpackages-filesystem for package: dejavu-fonts-common-2.33-6.el7.noarch
    ---> Package libtidy.x86_64 0:0.99.0-31.20091203.el7 will be installed
    ---> Package php-php-gettext.noarch 0:1.0.11-12.el7 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: php-mbstring for package: php-php-gettext-1.0.11-12.el7.noarch
    ---> Package php-tcpdf.noarch 0:6.2.11-1.el7 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: php-mbstring for package: php-tcpdf-6.2.11-1.el7.noarch
    --> Processing Dependency: php-bcmath for package: php-tcpdf-6.2.11-1.el7.noarch
    ---> Package phpMyAdmin.noarch 0:4.4.15.8-2.el7 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: php-mbstring >= 5.3.7 for package: phpMyAdmin-4.4.15.8-2.el7.noarch
    --> Running transaction check
    ---> Package fontpackages-filesystem.noarch 0:1.44-8.el7 will be installed
    ---> Package php-php-gettext.noarch 0:1.0.11-12.el7 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: php-mbstring for package: php-php-gettext-1.0.11-12.el7.noarch
    ---> Package php-tcpdf.noarch 0:6.2.11-1.el7 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: php-mbstring for package: php-tcpdf-6.2.11-1.el7.noarch
    --> Processing Dependency: php-bcmath for package: php-tcpdf-6.2.11-1.el7.noarch
    ---> Package phpMyAdmin.noarch 0:4.4.15.8-2.el7 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: php-mbstring >= 5.3.7 for package: phpMyAdmin-4.4.15.8-2.el7.noarch
    --> Finished Dependency Resolution
    Error: Package: php-php-gettext-1.0.11-12.el7.noarch (epel)
               Requires: php-mbstring
    Error: Package: phpMyAdmin-4.4.15.8-2.el7.noarch (epel)
               Requires: php-mbstring >= 5.3.7
    Error: Package: php-tcpdf-6.2.11-1.el7.noarch (epel)
               Requires: php-bcmath
    Error: Package: php-tcpdf-6.2.11-1.el7.noarch (epel)
               Requires: php-mbstring
     You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
     You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I Already installed php5, apache2, mysql, mysql-server, Mysql MariaDB
I also tried to install those packages one by one, no use!

But PHPMyAdmin is not installing, how to install this?

Comment: Find the repo with those packages and subscribe to it.

Comment: if I remember correctly, you would want to enable the "Optional" channel to your RedHat subscription to get those missing PHP packages.  I am unfamiliar with the preferred method doing such as I have not used RedHat in some time, so posting comment instead of answer